# Насколько надёжно использовать PHP short tags?

Tags: php, хостинг

Сабж. Много ли хостингов, где короткий открывающий тег отключён?

Comment: По-моему это самый маразматичный момент в PHP)

Comment: @Kremchik, я использую короткие теги только в одном случае:
синтаксис

    <? = 'text' ?>

вместо

    <?php echo 'text' ?>

Тут это очень удобно, а так да, от них нет смысла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

начиная с версии php 5.4 короткий тег вывода работает всегда вне зависимости от значения директивы short_open_tag. так что используем и не паримся по этому поводу. [пруф](http://www.php.ru/manual/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Но 5.4 ещё ой как не везде, кстати(

Comment: так то php 5.4 stable уже вышла, в течении полугода думаю будет опционально включена на продвинутых хостингах через год-два на остальных.

Comment: Мне вот интересно насчёт более старых - там часто ли можно встретить сервера с отключённой директивой этой. Вроде как обычно включена?
Кстати, смотрю, что короткие теги не подходят стандарту XHTML, а у меня как раз он.

Comment: еще не разу не встречал хостинг, где бы короткие теги были отключены. поправьте меня если я не прав, но мне кажется это две разные вещи когда отдаешь файл прошедший через php интерпретатор, и когда отдаешь xhtml со вставками php.

Comment: Да это то же самое.
А, хотя, я сам сейчас подумал - как может к XHTML относится PHP-написание. Ведь в готовом XHTML уже нету никакого PHP. Хм.

Comment: >> Спасибо. Но 5.4 ещё ой как не везде, кстати(
Еще 5.3 не везде, а вы про 5.4 ...

Comment: А где связь винды и версии php? Для нее тоже [есть сборки][1] и 5.3 и 5.4

  [1]: http://windows.php.net/download/

Comment: @KiTE, у меня опять этот лимит на комменты(
Я в тех сборках не нашёл модуля для Apache, если не ошибаюсь.